# Need Help With Custom Session Manager - How Do I Access Session Information?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have some questions about session management.

I have decided to use a custom session manager class to have more control 
over session state in my web site. I have started out by using Stephan Prodan's
Session Class [here](http://stefanprodan.spaces.live.com/?_c11_BlogPart_BlogPart=blogview&_c=BlogPart&partqs=cat%3DC%2523). You'll need to take a look to get a sense of what I 
am talking about.

1) My first question pertains to how I persist and access my session information
after a user authenticates (or doesn't). In his example, sessions are created
upon login / authentication as such:

```
    // Create new instance of session manager
    SessionManager<WorkbookProfile> sessionManager = 
        new SessionManager<WorkbookProfile>(10);

    //Register timeout event
    sessionManager.OnEntryTimeout += 
        new SessionEntryTimeoutDelegate<WorkbookProfile>(sessionManager_OnEntryTimeout);

    // Get the user's profile
    UserProfile profile = UserProfile.GetUserProfile(_membership.GetUserNameByEmail(Login1.UserName));

    //Log profile & start session
    sessionManager.startSession(ref profile);

    //Store on the session a user's object
    sessionManager.SetData("MyData", "UserObject", user.SessionId);
```

OK, I understand the above code. What I don't completely understand is how I can 
access session information as users interact with the system. For example,
take the below code:

```
public partial class MyClass : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private UserProfile _profile;
    private SessionManager<UserProfile> _session;

    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _session = new SessionManager<UserProfile>(10);
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string UserName = sessionManager[profile.SessionId].UserName;

        _profile = UserProfile.GetUserProfile(UserName);
    }

}
```

In the above code I need to pass the user's UserName to 
to the `GetUserProfile method in order to create an instance 
of the authenticated user's profile. But, I need
to have the profile object to access the SessionId. Sort of 
a Catch 22. What am I doing wrong here? How should I be accessing
session and profile information for each new page the user 
visits?

2) the importance of the database when using sessions?

My second question relates to the use of the DB with sessions. 
In Stefan's class, all session information is stored in a session 
object that persists as long as the user is authenticated. But, 
in other online reading, I have seen examples where programmers 
store session keys in a table in association with fk_profileid. 
What is the purpose of this? What is the best practice?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provided us with the provider model for doing this kind of thing.
By using the provider model we can replace any functionality we need to with a simple config statement.

By default session information is handled by the session state module:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatemodule.aspx

Here's where I would start creating my own:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587.aspx

Essentialy you should have a class that inherits this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatestoreproviderbase.aspx

And here's an example (pretty basic i'll admit):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178588.aspx

If you follow best practice (covered in the above links) you should be able to implement a custom session state provider that replaces the existing session state provider in about 2 to 4 hours (with a bit of time for figuring it out and tinkering).

This will mean that everything you need should be in the default pages "Session" variable.

However, using the provider model means you dont have to replace the existing provider, you could also run your custom provider along side the default one